# Мы, в зависимости от смысла(,) разумеется, можем прилагательные писать либо слитно, либо раздельно

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Мы, в зависимости от смысла(,) разумеется, можем прилагательные писать либо слитно, либо раздельно с «не», когда сзади идёт либо наречие «совсем», либо «вовсе», либо «абсолютно», «совершенно»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом [«в зависимости от»](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/v-zavisimosti-ot-chego), могут обособляться...
   > *Вернее сказать, всем людям, общавшимся с ним, включая жену и друзей, были свойственны, **в зависимости от** характера человека, все эти чувства к нему...* А. Фадеев, Молодая гвардия. *Обеденный стол, **в зависимости от** обстоятельств, превращался то в письменный, то в кровать, когда оставался ночевать кто-нибудь из друзей, приезжавших с фронта.* В. Каверин, Открытая книга.

Вы приняли решение обособить такой оборот. В этом случае вводное слово, в него входящее, запятыми не отделяется:
*Мы, **в зависимости от смысла разумеется,** можем прилагательные писать...*

2. > [**4.**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122) Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется: <...>
   > *В строгом смысле человек с десять, **разумеется в том числе и я,** не стоили этого назначения* (Акс.)...
3. Если же оборот с предлогом в предложении не обособлен, то вводное слово "разумеется" выделяется запятыми по общему правилу:
   *Мы в зависимости от смысла, **разумеется,** можем прилагательные писать...*

Comment: Можно уточнить? К обособленному обороту любое вводное слово можно отнести? Вводных слов много, они очень разные (по смыслу, структуре и т.д.). Исключений нет?